# Firebase upload mapping file 403

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to add the `firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping` task to my gradle build and while I feel that I'm close, I can't quite get the final step. I get a `403, Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.` error. I've updated my `google-services.json` file and grabbed a fresh private key from the firebase console. I'm running the command:

```
./gradlew --debug --stacktrace -PFirebaseServiceAccountFilePath=/home/me/tmp/firebase-crashreporting.json :app:firebaseUploadReleaseProguardMapping
```

I'm using Firebase version 11.4.2 libraries with google-services classpath 3.1.1 on Android Studio 3.0 beta 7. If there's any more information that would be helpful I'd be happy to provide it.

**UPDATE:**

I upgraded to Firebase plugin 1.1.4 but I'm still seeing the same issue.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from this Android client application \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it manually from the firebase console.

Comment: That won't work from a CI

Comment: Found any solution to this?